# DBIX class array of rows

Tags: dbix-class

How can I convert DBIX::Class resulset returned by a search call, into a plain array of hashes or array of arrays. I mean each row as an array/hash collected into an array.

Answer (score 0):

Use the included HashRefInflator result class as described in the docs.
Note that the data will be returned as coming from the database without any inflation or filtering.